# java maven docker jib published port fails

Tags: docker, maven, jib

I have a mavenized springboot application which I successfully dockerized by using [GoogleContainerTools jib](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin). But it fails to properly connect when I type the address of `http://localhost:8080` into browser on the host.

Section in maven build

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <to>
            <image>springboot-test</image>
        </to>
        <container>
            <ports>
                <port>8080</port>
            </ports>
            <environment>
                <spring.datasource.url>jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/postgres</spring.datasource.url>
                <spring.mongo.url>mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/mongo</spring.mongo.url>
            </environment>
            <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
            <format>OCI</format>
        </container>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

I run the setup by `maven clean compile jib:dockerBuild -f pom.xml`.

I do have a postgres database and mongodb connected to other containers as well, which properly starts up as the log tells.

The image build properly and runs as container as the log on Docker Desktop do claim.
When inspecting the container in my Docker Desktop it says on **Port** section that the port `8080/tcp` is `Not bound`. Accessing on the host system in the browser `http://localhost:8080` does not reach anything.

[image: Docker Desktop Container]

When [reading deeper into port exposure](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker/expose-vs-publish) there is differences between `publish` and `expose`. So far I got `publish` is for the exposure to the host and `expose` handles port access among different containers.
For example, I cannot really understand how to granularly setup this difference like having the containerized webapp (springboot-web) running on port 8080 and publish it to port 80 on the host system.

What am I missing?

(I am running everything on a Macbook with a Java 17 setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your maven command builds the container, not runs it.

You still need to explicitly map the ports, whether or not they are exposed/published in the build definition of the Docker image

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 image
```

Also, you shouldn't use IP addresses for other services in a Docker network, nor should you hard-code them as default environment variables

Comment: Works perfect as described by OneCricketeer; thank you! In the _Docker Desktop_ there is a `Copy docker run` in a container. (Why is this not also on the entry in the image section - do I have to try to start it before in order to modify it in order to make it run?) The docker run command issued by the Docker Desktop I can modify and use to execute in the console and that works perfectly. The Docker Desktop will automatically list the running container. It would be nice to have that modifiable within the Docker Desktop - or even as proposal give the GUI some field to modify that for startup.